# Discret light sabre circuit

Tags: led

I built a light sabre some time ago [Light Sabre](http://www.instructables.com/id/Darth-Maul-LED-light-saber/) using a sledge-hammer on ant approach with a micro-controller. Does anyone have a circuit that would do something similar just with discrete components?

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Darth-Maul-LED-light-saber/

Comment: You don't want to do that with discretes. The lowest I'd go is a LM3914 with larger sink transistors.

Comment: You want to sequentially light multiple segments of leds? The discreet parts needed will out cost any average microcontroller and programmer. You can get a msp430 launch pad or arduino for less than 10 shipped.

Comment: lol, I had the 3914 datasheet up. thought it might be a bit tricky creating a smooth 0-5v and back again

Comment: Nah, a CCS into a cap makes a decent ramp generator.

Comment: Why not just use WS2812s? Then you don't need to worry about drive transistors; all you need is a beefy power supply and a teeny tiny MCU. Oh, and it would be able to do arbitrary RGB patterns.

Comment: @Jasen: Pin 9 selects dot or bargraph mode; there's no need to modify the LED connections.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it seems  I mis-remembered how those chips work,

Answer (score 1):

something like this perhaps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmiso3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

it does the power up effect, but doesn't have a power down effect,
4 LEDs shown, but you cad add add more stages to the right, and add more parallel LEDs if needed. the horizontal resistor and the capacitors control the speed, reduce them to make it faster.